# Gradle errors when using pro guard

Tags: java, android, proguard, androidx

I am using `pro guard` for optimizing my android app. But I am getting below error on debugging. I have tried to keep warnings inside `proguard-rules-pro file` but still, it isn't solving and then my build is taking longer time without completing. Why this error occurs, how can I solve it?

When I turn to minify enabled to false it works, but I need to set true so as to optimize app size. I am stuck. Any help is appreciated.

> Error:
>   androidx.media.AudioAttributesCompatParcelizer: can't find referenced field 'android.support.v4.media.AudioAttributesImpl mImpl' in program class `enter code here`android.support.v4.media.AudioAttributesCompat
>   androidx.media.AudioAttributesImplApi21Parcelizer: can't find referenced field 'android.media.AudioAttributes mAudioAttributes' in program class android.support.v4.media.AudioAttributesImplApi21

1.Proguard-rules.pro File: Added this code but no use

```
    /*
    #-dontwarn androidx.**

    #-keep class androidx.** { *; }

    #-keep interface androidx.** { *; }

    #-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }


    #-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }

    */
```

2. Build.gradle(app) file

```
release {
 shrinkResources false
    minifyEnabled true
                `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),` `'proguard-rules.pro'`
  //Other parameters
  debuggable false
  jniDebuggable false
  renderscriptDebuggable false
  pseudoLocalesEnabled false
  zipAlignEnabled true
 }      

debug {
  debuggable true
  minifyEnabled true
  shrinkResources false
                    `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
```

Comment: Why you commented all code from Proguard-rules.pro file?

Comment: Actually i didn't show my pro guard file. What i meant that i added that keep&dontwarn code in my proguard file as found in some queries related to my problem from stack , but adding that codes dont solve my error instead it takes gradle build long time . If you need i can upload my pro guard file for checking

Comment: Yes, Please upload.

Comment: I think it is solved, I upgraded my gradle version from 3.2.1 to 3.4.1 . It is working fine . Probably it may be some bug in that version . I replaced some resources in my project before that . I am still checking if there any issue come. Thanks for everybody's help and time - @pallavi-tapkir,